# SuggestBox with KeyUp Handler-Arrow keys not working

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, suggestbox

I have a `SuggestBox` with `KeyUpHandler` attached to it to call the service to fetch suggestions. Now, the problem is, when I type the text and suggestions are displayed, if I press down arrow key, the focus moves back to first suggestion always(due to KeyUp I guess). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `GWT` `SuggestBox` , you don't need to attach a `KeyUpHandler` to call the service...The `SuggestBox` does that for you by default. Due to your adding of the `keyUpHandler` to call the service it is making an extra call to call the service each time you press a key and hence the behavior.

Example :

```
   MultiWordSuggestOracle dropItems = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();
   dropItems.add("One");
   dropItems.add("Two");
   dropItems.add("Three");
   dropItems.add("Four");

   SuggestBox box = new SuggestBox(dropItems);
```